# Word meaning not knowing when to stop

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that means "not knowing when to stop"? I haven't been able to think of one as of yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does rather depend on context. *Reckless* will often fit, but so might *unrestrained, undisciplined, careless,* and several others.

Personally I think the best "single-word" answer is [intemperate](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=intemperate&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=Pw-zTv6JFIOg8QOy37GBBQ&sqi=2&ved=0CB8QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=e324bf9dcf381bc0&biw=1237&bih=846) - *having or showing a lack of self-control; immoderate*. It's particularly associated with not knowing when to stop drinking alcohol, but that doesn't prevent its use in other contexts.

Note that *temper* has many meanings; in "intemperate" it's the verb *to moderate, or tone down*.

Comment: I like intemperate, that seems like what I'm going for. +1

Answer (score 3):

Depending on context, you may use [*unrestrained*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/unrestrained?q=unrestrained) or [*unbridled*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/unbridled?q=unbridled).

Answer (score 3):

Incessant.
continuing without interruption; ceaseless; unending

Comment: -1: *Incessant* is normally applied to abstract things, such as **noise**, which can't meaningfully "know" anything, let alone when to stop.

Answer (score 2):

*Compulsive* might do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Some possibilities: *[blithe](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blithe)*, sense 2, "Indifferent, careless, showing a lack of concern";
*[uncurbed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uncurbed)*, "Unlimited; unrestricted"; *[gung ho](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gung_ho)*, "Very enthusiastic or energetic"; *[high-handed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/high-handed)*, "Using power or authority without proper consideration for the feelings or rights of others"; and perhaps *manic, speed demon, overboard, over the top, heavy-handed, lead-footed, [roughshod](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/roughshod), [heedless](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heedless)*.

Some facetious suggestions: *unbrakeable*; *brakeless*; *brake-challenged*.